# Div stops javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a javascript function to update a database table when a form item is selected. This all works just fine.

Javascrpit:

```
 function changeFunc(){
 var selectBox = document.getElementById("supervisor");
 var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
 if(selectedValue = 1){
     var jqxhr = $.ajax("<?php echo $web_root; ?      
  >/file/reminder/supervisor_reminder.php?super=1")
                  .done(function(){ alert("success, supervisor Helen has    
   been alerted."); })
                  .fail(function(){ alert("error"); });

    }

   }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="supervisor">
 <form action="" method="">
    <label>Supervisor Alert</label>
        <select id="supervisor" onchange="changeFunc()">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Helen</option>
            <option value="2">Nancy</option>
            <option value="3">Joyce</option>
            <option value="4">Bob</option>
            <option value="5">Herb</option>
        </select>    
  </form>
  </div>
```

When I wrap the form with the div tags the javascript function does not work. I wanted to be able to hide the form once the table has been updated. So I wrapped in the div for that purpose. But that stops the javascript from working and I was just wonder if someone could tell me why. Or how to hide the table maybe using css.

Comment: You're using the id "supervisor" twice. Your code expects it to be a `<select>` but you've added the `<div>` and used the same id.  The id has to be unique, so use a different string for the `<div>`.

Comment: Also, FWIW, since you are using jQuery, why not use the `$()` handler to select elements? Example: `var $selectBox = $('#supervisor');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID `supervisor` Should be used only once !

So for eg, update `<div id="supervisor">` to `<div id="supervisorBox">` and use #supervisorBox to hide this box.

For eg with:

```
$("#supervisorBox").hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo have two elements with same ID, so change the outmost to

```
<div id="supervisorContainer">
```

Comment: OIC said the blind man.... Thanks for answering the dumb question. Could see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave the div and the select the same id. The div needs a different id.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two HTML elements with the same ID. Change your `<div>` or your `select` ID to be different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using the same ID for the div as for the select control.

IDs MUST be unique. otherwise the first occurence will be used, which - in your case - is the div container.

So with the DIV container your JS variable "selectBox" is pointing on the DIV, not the select control.

SOLUTION: Change one of the IDs to another (unique) one and use the ID of the select control in your JS code.

```
    <div id="supervisor_div">
    <form action="" method="">
        <label>Supervisor Alert</label>
        <select id="supervisor" onchange="changeFunc()">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Helen</option>
            <option value="2">Nancy</option>
            <option value="3">Joyce</option>
            <option value="4">Bob</option>
            <option value="5">Herb</option>
        </select>    
    </form>
</div>
```